# How to generate data files with some statistic properties across multiple files?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability

I will generate X json files of the same format as following:

```json
  {
    "username" : "user"+i,
    "random" : "7389761539"
  }
```

Each file has a filed named "random" that contains some random 10-digits string.
Here is the function I am using to generate such strings:

```py
def generateRandomStringWith10Digits():
    result = ""
    chars = "0123456789"
    charsLength = len(chars)
    for i in range(10):
        result += chars[math.floor(random.random() * charsLength)]
        
    return result
```

The problem is that I don't want the random field values generated across the X documents to be completely arbitrary. Instead, I want the number of json files with the same "random" field value to follow the normal distribution of some given average and standard deviation.

For example, I want on average 10 json files with the same "random" value field as shown in the following figure:
[image]

Comment: See [np.random.randn](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

Comment: @JérômeRichard yeah but I don't know how to relate it to the document generation stuff :/

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want the number of json files with the same "random" field value to follow the normal distribution of some given average and standard deviation." The "number" of files will be discrete, first of all, while normal distribution is continuous.

Comment: Second, are you saying you basically want there to be `x` number of files containing the same randomly generated value, where `x` is the mean of whichever distribution you end up selecting, then smaller numbers of files with another random value, then even smaller numbers with another random value, where these "numbers" follow something resembling normal distribution?  How will these "numbers" relate to the `X` total number of documents you mentioned?  That can't be independent of the distribution parameters you select.